# Calculating time difference in MySQL but taking events into account

Tags: mysql, time

I have a table structured like this

```
index - date ------ time ----- status
1       2015-01-01  13:00:00   start
2       2015-01-01  13:10:00   continue
3       2015-01-01  13:20:00   continue
4       2015-01-01  13:30:00   end
5       2015-01-01  13:30:00   ready
6       2015-01-01  13:40:00   start
7       2015-01-01  13:50:00   continue
8       2015-01-01  15:00:00   end
```

and what I would like to do is count the time between start and end (ie. index 1-4 is 30min, 6-8 is 20min), but taking into account only the first start and first end, so that the query doesn't choose the time difference of index 1-8. Which query is used to calculate time difference between two statues (start-end) and show the result for multiple instances of start-end without them getting batched into one event?

Comment: In general, it's best to store dates and times as a single datetime entity.

Comment: And why 6-7 (which is 10mins BTW)?

Comment: There are multiple 'continue' timestamps in between start/end that add a sensor value, which is in another column, but isn't directly related to the question.

Comment: In regards to the single datetime stamp - yes, I agree, I'm not sure why I decided to separate them, but the database is already running and I don't want to rethink that. Time is more important, since 99.9% of the events will be less than 6 hours duration. They can roll over midnight though.

Comment: so, did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

For each start, use a query to get the next end time.  Then, just calculate the difference.  The logic is something like this:

```
select t.*, timestampdiff(second, dt, next_dt)
from (select t.*, addtime(t.date, t.time) as dt,
             (select addtime(t2.date, t2.time)
              from table t2
              where addtime(t2.date, t2.time) > addtime(t.date, t.time) and
                    status = 'end'
              order by addtime(t2.date, t2.time) desc
              limit 1
             ) as next_dt
      from table t
      where status = 'start'
     ) t
```

This assumes that your date and time columns are stored using the proper database types (`date` and `time`).  If you are storing them as something else, you will have to needlessly complicate the logic to convert them to the internal formats.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this out. I have fixed the formats in the example above, the fields are indeed date/time format in the real database.

Comment: What does the 't' following the last end bracket represent? The db table name?

Comment: @Fid . . . It is a table alias and required for subqueries in MySQL (and some other databases).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,dt DATETIME NOT NULL
,status VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1       ,'2015-01-01 13:00:00' ,  'start'),
(2       ,'2015-01-01 13:10:00' ,  'continue'),
(3       ,'2015-01-01 13:20:00' ,  'continue'),
(4       ,'2015-01-01 13:30:00' ,  'end'),
(5       ,'2015-01-01 13:30:00' ,  'ready'),
(6       ,'2015-01-01 13:40:00' ,  'start'),
(7       ,'2015-01-01 13:50:00' ,  'continue'),
(8       ,'2015-01-01 15:00:00' ,  'end');

SELECT x.*
     , TIMEDIFF(MIN(y.dt),x.dt)diff 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.dt >= x.dt 
 WHERE x.status = 'start' 
   AND y.status = 'end' 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id;
+----+---------------------+--------+----------+
| id | dt                  | status | diff     |
+----+---------------------+--------+----------+
|  1 | 2015-01-01 13:00:00 | start  | 00:30:00 |
|  6 | 2015-01-01 13:40:00 | start  | 01:20:00 |
+----+---------------------+--------+----------+
```