# MySQL Transform state change dates to state durations

Tags: mysql

So basically I have a table where user's state **changes** get logged (user goes online, user goes offline etc)

I want to create a table that has the **durations** of these states (user is online from [date] to [date], user is offline from [date] to [date])

How does one go about doing such a thing?
Is it even possible with just MySQL statements?

**Addiotional info**: the dates are stored as unix timestamp with a data type of `int(12)`

Comment: I guess only logging the Login time is enough. Coz they would be offline automatically logged off for the rest of the time.

Comment: There are also other states like 'do not disturb' and 'away' but for the sake of simplicity I didn't mention those

Comment: The usual way is to just log the state change (2 columns: time and new state) and then do something like [Calculating time difference in MySQL but taking events into account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30835350) (or one of the [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3017468) questions (and if you are on MySQL 8, mention it, then you can use ctes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought about iterating trough the rows in a procedure, but then I realised that `UPDATE` also iterates through them.

I added three new columns to the existing table (instead of creating a new table for this), which are the following:

- rowid (for identifying the row in the function)
- endtime
- duration

I created a function for getting the endtime for a row.

Here are the steps for what I wanted to achive
*(each step is a seperate query)*

## 1: Drop the function if it exists

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS NEXTDATE;
```

## 2: Create the function

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION NEXTDATE (thisrowid mediumint(9), thistime int(12))
RETURNS int(12)
DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    
    SELECT userid INTO @userid FROM status WHERE rowid = thisrowid;
    SELECT status INTO @status FROM status WHERE rowid = thisrowid;
    SELECT MIN(time) INTO @endtime FROM status WHERE userid = @userid AND
        time > thistime AND status != @status;

    RETURN @endtime;

END;
```

## 3: Update rows

```sql
UPDATE status
SET endtime = NEXTDATE(rowid,time), duration = endtime - time
```